# How can I attach a script to a created window in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In `background.js` I create a window like so:

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "popup.html", width: 300, height: 250, type: "popup", focused: true});
```

The `<head>` tag of `popup.html` contains the following:

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

And in popup.js I have

```
console.log("Hello, World!");
```

When I test out the extension, the popup window opens just fine, but nothing shows in the console. Is what I'm trying to do possible? What could be going wrong? No errors are shown in the console, including when I inspect the background page from the extensions list.

Comment: The code is correct. Apparently you're looking at the wrong console. In the newly opened window right click anything and click `Inspect`, then see the console pane/tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm That was it, or at least half the problem - I'm getting errors when I try to access the popup.html DOM from popup.js, now. Is it possible to access the DOM from there?

Comment: Of course it's possible. The only well-known caveat (which has lots of solutions) is that when the script is loaded from HEAD there's no BODY yet in the document.

Comment: @wOxxOm Of course. I'm working in a new environment so I'm overthinking things. Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close as "cannot reproduce".